# Webpack Obfuscator Identifier has already been declared

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, obfuscation

I just obfuscated my code for a chrome extension and I keep getting `Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'a' has already been declared` the file starts with `const a = ...`.

This happens even if I change const to var.

On the previous version of the chrome extension, this worked.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I had to put all of my content scripts into block scope in order to avoid variable collision.